# Instantiate View Controller with Tab Bar controller and Navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, deep-linking

Okay so I'm integrating deep linking into my app and I'm using a Tab Bar Controller and Navigation Bar Controller. So how do I instantiate the destination `UIViewController`? 
[image]

(the one that has like the crosshair in the middle is the one that I want to refer to)

Comment: In which class do you want to instantiate your "the one that has like the crosshair in the middle"?

Comment: It's UIViewController class names MapViewController